# Want to initialize multiple ids as a variable and change the option value of the select tag using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to initialize multiple variables in the below script. The present script changes the text of the `id="Widget1727491790"` with `<option>` having `value=""` to 'Select Quantity' instead of displaying '- Choose -'.

So I want to do the same for multiple ids i.e. `id="Widget1727491790"` as well as `id="Widget1315144869"`.

Note: Need a JQuery solution only as I don't has access to the HTML DOM, as its a third party [Plugin](https://formfacade.com/) used for Google Forms to customize the form according to your branding, giving it a website look.

HTML DOM:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Widget1727491790" name="entry.1395838924">
    <option value="">- Choose -</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="Widget1315144869" name="entry.2091496022">
    <option value="">- Choose -</option>
    <option value="250">250</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="750">750</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Widget1727491790 option[value=""]').text('Select Quantity');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should spend some time reading the [jQuery manual pages](https://api.jquery.com/). Then the following will become quite obvious to you:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Widget1727491790,#Widget1315144869') 
  .find('option[value=""]')
  .text('Select Quantity');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="Widget1727491790" name="entry.1395838924">
<option value="">- Choose -</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="Widget1315144869" name="entry.2091496022">
<option value="">- Choose -</option>
<option value="250">250</option>
<option value="500">500</option>
<option value="750">750</option>
<option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an attribute "selected" to the desired default value  tag should do the trick.

```
<option value="" selected>- Choose -</option>
```

Comment: Actually, its on a website https://formfacade.com/, which I don't have access to, its a plugin which helps you customize google forms, so I can use the CSS and JavaScript only.